# Find Elements by Xpath not giving the correct element in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

In the following example, I have to click only for Jet Airways. It appears that the xpath selected is correct since it gives the right only from the selection.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7s3v.png

However when this same is being pulled by Selenium WebDriver, it says element not visible. But it still gives a Button with zero length text string. as given in watch window.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVZhk.png

I would appreciate if anyone can help me to point if any error I am making since I am new to VBA

Comment: You probably need to first click to open the dropdown & then look for the element

Comment: Put the actual error, code here not just picture links perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if your XPath is correct and is locating the right static element...
You may use this for locating 'Jet Airways'

```
//label[text()[contains(.,'Jet Airways')]]
```

Also, using `.click()`, try clicking on the 'Airlines' dropdown before locating the 'Airlines Dropdown' XPath

```
//span[@title='Airlines']
```

---

### Update:

```
public class SkyScanner 
{



    static String chkBxXpth = "//label[@class='dropdown-item cfx']/input[@checked]";

        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
        {       
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("http://skyscanner.cntraveller.com/en-GB/flights#/result?originplace=AUH&destinationplace=LHR");

            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@title='Airlines']")));
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@title='Airlines']")).click();
            List<WebElement> chkBx = driver.findElements(By.xpath(chkBxXpth));
            for(WebElement i : chkBx)
            {
                actions.moveToElement(i).click().perform();
            }
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()[contains(.,'Jet Airways')]]")).click();
        }

    }
```

Comment: It appears correct to me - https://www.screencast.com/t/IIhZ6SoXpLxd
Can you please provide the reason for considering it to be wrong? :)

Comment: Thanks for your support. However there are two parts to the text. it clicks the Airlines and basically unselects it. I need to achieve the reverse. Select only Jet Airways.

Comment: @BlueMoon I have added the code sample to my answer. That should work. Basically, I'm deselecting all the available checkboxes and finally selecting only the Jet Airways.
Note: It throws **Stale Element Exception** at times. Please find a way to handle it.

Comment: Thx for your great efforts ! I wish some day I could be as efficient as you. Just a quick question. Currently I am copying xpath from chrome developer tools, however your xpath were different. Is there some reading material or some logic where I can learn this stuff.

Comment: Here you go - http://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html
Good and simple enough to start with

Comment: @ Shreyas. Yesterday did some research to see if I can come up with the element direct. I tried to build on your xpath and came up with this //label[text()[contains(.,'Jet')]]/*[2]/*[1] This points to the correct element but does not click it. Scratching my head over it again and again why would it exhibit such a behaviour. In the past also I have managed to click elements like this. Since you are too good, I humbly wanted to check with you any idea why would it not do the same ?

Comment: @BlueMoon, your xpath points to 'only' text that pops when you mouse hover over JetAirways. You should click on the checkbox. Clicking on the text wouldn't serve the purpose in this case.
PS: I'm a rookie too, not "too good" as you describe :)